# Storybook v7, Element type is invalid: expected a string but got: object

Tags: reactjs, storybook, storybook-addon, nextjs-storybook

Framework: Nextjs 12
Storybook v7

SideNav.tsx is simple function based component.
Is there something i am missing?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM4RQ.png)

SideNav.stories.tsx

```
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';

import SideNav from './SideNav';

const meta: Meta<typeof SideNav> = { component: SideNav };
export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<typeof SideNav>;

export const Default: Story = {
  render: () => <SideNav className="sidenav" />,
};
```